# Plugin GMF

Tags: java

Comment une image devient un noeud dans la palette et on peut l'inserer dans la zone de dessin

[translation:](http://translate.google.com)

How a picture becomes a node in the palette and can be inserted in the drawing area

Comment: Thanks toolkit for providing the translation.

Answer (score 2):

First, to bad to see your question voted down, not sure why that is; the question is valid.  Sorry I can only reply in English.  Review this document ([GMF Developer Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.gmf.doc/reference/api/runtime/overview-summary.html)) on GMF paying close attention to the figures II and III to ensure understanding of views/nodes vs editParts vs figures.

The examples really show you how to use all the different plug-in extensions together to create the whole user interaction you are expecting.

Second, there are palette examples included in eclipse GMF.  Eclipse -> New Example -> GMF. The palette requires a plug-in type and classes outside of the drawing/picture plug-ins.  I have validated that the **GMF logic example** shows how to use the palette plug-in and classes to accomplish this. Just in case the link to installing the examples ([Install Examples if not already.](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.gmf.doc/reference/api/runtime/overview-summary.html))